# problem to get radio input box value in jquery

Tags: jquery

guys i need to get the value of  a  input radio box  so i wrote this code

```
if ($("input[@name='notify']:checked").val() == '1'){
    var notifyme=1;
} else {
    var notifyme=0;
}
```

but everytime i send the request through php function it says notifyme var is 1  and even i checked  0 radio box  it still says the value is 1

html part

```
<input type="radio" name ='notify' value="1" >YES 
<input type="radio" name ='notify' value="0" >NO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lose the @ prefix on the attribute. The xslt based syntax has been removed since 1.4+

```
if ( $("input[name='notify']:checked").val() ){
    var notifyme=1;
} else {
    var notifyme=0;
}
```

Comment: ["deprecated"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) implies that the feature still exists and hasn't been removed yet, but should be avoided because it may be removed in the future.  It's only deprecated, so having the @ there shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just,

```
var notifyme = $('input[name=notify]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

looks correct to me, http://www.jsfiddle.net/sjRcZ/1/
You sure that jquery is loading?

Comment: It's not, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/XgGWH/. Works fine. Now add the `@` and watch it explode.

Comment: @Andy E, interesting stuff :)

Comment: Interesting. `@` works when `:checked` filter is present. Without it, the expression becomes invalid. Better to let go off `@`.

Comment: @Anurag: yeah, there's definitely something weird going on there.  I couldn't find any docs on whether `@name` for attributes was removed or just deprecated.  Oh well, I guess it doesn't matter that much - just don't do it like you said :-)